# Updates to the database deletes older data from the same session on the socket

Tags: python, django, database, django-channels

I'm building a tic tac toe game which you can play online. I wanted to save the win / lose count of each user and I'm using Django 3.2, channels 3 and channels_presence with Python 3.9

I've built the socket and the client successfully and now you can play as much games as you would like.

**The problem** is that the score I try to save is stored in the database, but after another game the score returns back to zero.

So if two users are playing in a room and user 1 won 2 games, the score would get updated, and then if the other user won a game their score would be 1 and the user 1 score would be reset to zero

**My User model**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    won_games = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lost_games = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    draw_games = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def win(self):
        self.won_games += 1
        self.save() 

    def lose(self):
        self.lost_games += 1
        self.save() 

    def draw(self):
        self.draw_games += 1
        self.save()
```

I've put this into the receive function in my consumers.py

```py
class GameConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    #some code
    def receive(self, text_data):

        if text_data['type'] == 'completed':
            self_channel = Presence.objects.get(channel_name=self.channel_name)
            competitor = self_channel.room.presence_set.filter(
                                    ~Q(channel_name=self_channel)
                                   ).first().user
            user = self.scope['user']
            if competitor:
                competitor.win()
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user.lose()
    return
```

I'm relying on the other user's message to confirm the win, so no one can send fake wins to the socket

I've tried to delete all the users from the database, migrate my database, change the way of changing the property won_games as you can see, but the problem is that it returns back to it's default after losing.

If you can help me here is the full source code
https://github.com/ahmedyasserays/XO-online

Comment: You should look at [using `F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f) to avoid race conditions in code like yours.

Comment: thank you very much. this doc helped me a lot @AKX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've fixed this , the problem was in the `user = self.scope['user']` part .
As you now on initiating the connection to the consumer a new consumer instance is created in the memory from your class with some attributes like this `self.scope` updating the database with new data on wining from another instance doesn't not affect all instances , instead other instances would still have objects that haven't updated their data yet, in our case it's the `self.scope['user']` which would still have older values of won_games that would override the updated values when we try to save it so the fix is just to add `user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user.id)` before applying the `user.lose()` method